# displaying live result from edit text to text view

Tags: java, android

I am creating a small golf app that includes a score card. I am facing an issue displaying the user's live score in a text view. The live score consists of their score for the hole - the par. I am using `editText.setOnEditorActionListener` in a for loop with the goal that it will keep doing the subtraction until all the scores are entered.

So far, it partially works after one score is entered. By partially, I mean it will only display the user's first entered score, and if I add a score on another hole, it will just add the first score again and disregard any other input from the user. I was hoping to try with two-way data binding, but that failed. If there isn’t enough context, I’ll gladly post what ever is missing or gladly accept guidance towards proper data binding implementation.

Here is the code

```
    List<EditText> userScores = new ArrayList<>();
    userScores.add(etUserHole1);
    userScores.add(etUserHole2);
    userScores.add(etUserHole3);
    userScores.add(etUserHole4);
    userScores.add(etUserHole5);
    userScores.add(etUserHole6);
    userScores.add(etUserHole7);
    userScores.add(etUserHole8);
    userScores.add(etUserHole9);

    List<Integer> coursePars = new ArrayList<>();
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar1.getText().toString()));
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar2.getText().toString()));
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar3.getText().toString()));
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar4.getText().toString()));
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar5.getText().toString()));
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar6.getText().toString()));
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar7.getText().toString()));
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar8.getText().toString()));
    coursePars.add(Integer.parseInt(tvPar9.getText().toString()));

    for (int i = 0; i < userScores.size(); i++) {
        userScores.get(i).setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                int j = 0;
                if (actionId == j) {
                    userSumOfHoles += Integer.parseInt(userScores.get(j).getText().toString()) - coursePars.get(j);
                    tvCurrentScoreUser.setText(String.valueOf(userSumOfHoles));
                    j++;
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `userScores.get(j)` this will always be the `etUserHole1` `EditText` field since you `int j = 0` two lines before that.  Similar for `coursePars.get(j)`.  Use the `v` for the score.  For the par it will require a bit more logic.

Comment: @Gardener I can’t believe I didn’t catch that… I’ll give that a try thank you!

Comment: @Gardener would you mind elaborating more if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer intended to give you some ideas to finalize your approach.

This line in the `onEditorAction` callback:

```
userSumOfHoles += Integer.parseInt(userScores.get(j).getText().toString()) - coursePars.get(j);
```

can be replaced with:

```
userSumOfHoles += Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString()) - holeParRating;
```

It is not necessary to index into `userScores` for the `EditText`/`TextView` since you are provided it in the callback : `v`.  Just to be clear: when the callback is invoked the system provides the original `EditText`/`TextView` instance for convenience.  So in theory you could use only one listener for all your processing.

Now the more complex part is how to "lookup" the par rating for the hole.  It **may** be possible (I have not tested) to use the `TextView` as a key to find the `indexOf` of the view in the `userScores` list and use that same index to get the par in the `coursePars` list - since you populated them as correlating.

**may** : this assumes the equals method of a `TextView` is adequate for lookup in this scenario.

```
holeParRating = coursePars.get(userScores.indexOf(v));
```

And so the entire listener code:

```
int userScoresIdx = userScores.indexOf(v);
if (userScoresIdx >= 0) {
    // log info for userScoresIdx to verify it properly finds proper index
    holeParRating = coursePars.get(userScoresIdx);
    userSumOfHoles += Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString()) - holeParRating;
    tvCurrentScoreUser.setText(String.valueOf(userSumOfHoles));
} else {
    // log an error for debugging
}
```

And eliminate the `j` variable since it was not used correctly.

I'm also assuming that `actionId` is not relevant to your processing since it was not mentioned as an issue.